# Renaming one file (and nothing more than ONE file) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, character, filenames, substitution

**The problem**

I constantly find myself in need of quick-method to rename a random file here and there while I work. I need to bring these filenames down to a structure compatible with web standards and some personal needs. A few examples below:

```
When I find                         I need
----------------------------------  -----------------------------------------
Welcome to the party.JPG            welcome_to_the_party.jpg
Instructions (and some other tips)  instructions_and_some_other_tips
Bar Drinks – The Best Recipes       bar_drinks_the_best_recipes
La mañana del águila y el ratón     la_manana_del_aguila_y_el_raton
```

Basically I need:

- all uppercase characters to become lowercase
- spaces to become underscore
- some other special characters and diacritics for other languages to become their closest match (á is a, é is e, ç is c, and so on...)
- Symbols like ( ) [ ] { } ' ; , to completely dissapear
- Perhaps some replacements (optional) as: # = no; @ = at or & = and

**Not the question, but just FYI and you can see the big picture**

I will be using a registry entry [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell...] so I can call a batch file and/or a PowerShell Script by right-clicking the desired file, passing the argument information (the file in question) to the script that way.

**My guesses**

I have been looking closely at PowerShell Scripts, but I am not very knowledgeable about this area yet and all the solutions provided so far are addressing **the entire folder** (Dir/Get-ChildItem) instead of **a specific file**.

For example, I was successful using the line below (PowerShell) to replace all spaces by underscore, but then it affects other files in the directory as well.

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “ “,”_“ }
```

Again, I do not need to address this problem for the entire folder, since I already have ways of doing so using software like Total Commander.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Ruy

Comment: With a batch file you would just use multiple set statements to replace one character with another.  It is basic string replacement. So to replace a space with an underscore: `set var=%var: =_%`

Comment: We also have a batch file function over on Dostips.com to do lower case conversion. http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.toLower

Comment: Why are you using smart quotes? That won't work ...

Comment: If you want a Powershell solution then please remove the batch-file tag from your question.

Comment: As @Squashman already stated, most of your task can be done by simple [substring replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html); the only quite challenging thing might be replacing consecutive characters like _space_`-`_space_ by a single underscore, but [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) may be of service for that; anyway, you need to show your own efforts as StackOverflow is not a free code writing service!

Comment: The old Unix `TR` command would come in handy but PS should be able to do everything that TR can do.  Looks like PS can do character classes so you should be able to easily translate control and punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

may be this code can help you

```
    function Remove-Diacritics([string]$String)
    {
        $objD = $String.Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormD)
        $sb = New-Object Text.StringBuilder

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $objD.Length; $i++) {
            $c = [Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($objD[$i])
            if($c -ne [Globalization.UnicodeCategory]::NonSpacingMark) {
              [void]$sb.Append($objD[$i])
            }
          }

        return("$sb".Normalize([Text.NormalizationForm]::FormC))
    }

    function Clean-String([string]$String)
    {
        return(Remove-Diacritics ($String.ToLower() -replace "#", "no" -replace "\@", "at" -replace "&", "and" -replace "\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\}|'|;|\,", "" -replace " ", "_"))
    }


    $youfile="C:\tmp4\121948_DRILLG.tif"
    $younewnamefile=Clean-String $youfile
    Rename-Item -Path $youfile $younewnamefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this script somewhere (let's call it WebRename.ps1):

```
$old = $args -join ' '
$new = $old.ToLower().Replace(' ', '_')
# add all the remaining transformations you need here
Rename-Item $old $new
```

In the registry use this as the command (with your own path of course):

```
PowerShell -c C:\WebRename.ps1 "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to be able to do this quickly and always want the same changes to be made you can add the following function to a .psm1 file and then place the file in one of your module folders (C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules is the most common one) you'll be able to just call WebRename-File *filePath* any time you need to quickly rename a file, the function is set up in such a way as to work fine if you pass in a single file path or you can pipe the results of a get-childitem to it if you ever do find the need to do bulk renames.

```
function WebRename-File {
    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      $filePath
    )

    begin{}
    Process{
        foreach($path in $filePath){
            $newPath = $path.ToLower()
            $newPath = $newPath.Replace(' ','_')

            ###add other operations here###

            Rename-Item -Path $path -NewName $newPath
        }
    }
    end{}
}
```

Comment: I had no luck. I tried the code directly from a .ps1 as well as a module .psm1 and the files don't change. :( I do thank you for your time and your code is most elegant!